# How auto refresh widgets and update api data in every 30secs?

Tags: json, flutter, api, dart

I am  developing a cricket live score application, I develop a score card and i want to update score according to my  JSON API data and refresh widgets. what should i need to do? i am using http request as Network request. And when i change the activity  and turned back to livescore() scores are updated (Reloaded) but here i want that staying on the same activity Scores updates. I am using Future Builder.

Code Samples:
**LiveScore  card area:**

```
  LiveMatch() {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: getlivescore(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Map> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return const Center(
              child: SizedBox(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(
            strokeWidth: 2,
            color: Color(0xff38547C),
          )));
        }
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: [
                  Text("Live Match"),
                  Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(16)),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      ImageIcon(
                        AssetImage("assets/images/ball.png"),
                        size: 10,
                        color: Colors.red[800],
                      ),
                      Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(1)),
                      Text("Live"),
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: [
                  Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Row(children: [
                        CircleAvatar(
                          backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                              "${snapshot.data!["data"][0]['image_path1']}"),
                          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                        ),
                        Text("${snapshot.data!["data"][0]['name1']}"),
                        // ImageIcon(
                        //   AssetImage("assets/images/ball.png"),
                        //   size: 10,
                        //   color: Colors.red[800],
                        // )
                      ]),
                      Row(children: [
                        CircleAvatar(
                          backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                              "${snapshot.data!["data"][0]['image_path2']}"),
                          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                        ),
                        Text("${snapshot.data!["data"][0]['name2']}"),
                        ImageIcon(
                          AssetImage("assets/images/ball.png"),
                          size: 10,
                          color: Colors.red[800],
                        )
                      ]),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      CircleAvatar(
                        child: Text("vs"),
                        backgroundColor: Color(0xff38547C),
                        foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                        radius: 13,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: [
                      Column(
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            "${livescore['data'][0]['score1']}",
                            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          ),
                          Row(
                            children: [
                              //overs
                              Text("overs" +
                                  "${livescore['data'][0]['overs1']}"),
                              Text(
                                "    " + "${livescore['data'][0]['wickets1']}",
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Column(
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            "${livescore['data'][0]['score2']}",
                            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          ),
                          Row(
                            children: [
                              //overs
                              Text("overs" +
                                  "${livescore['data'][0]['overs2']}"),
                              Text(
                                " out " + "${livescore['data'][0]['wickets2']}",
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Text("${snapshot.data!['data'][0]['note']}"),
                ],
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(3),
              )
            ],
          );
        } else {
          return const Text('Network Error');
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

Image:
[image: 2nd Innings]
[image: 1st Innings]

Answer (score 1):

As you're using Rest APIs hence you would have to call your GET score API every certain duration (lets say 5 seconds). But I won't recommend you doing that as it would be a very costly solution.

Here is the code anyways:

```
 Timer timer;
 @override
  void initState() {
    timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 30),(t){
      yourAPICallingFunction();
    });
    super.initState();
  }
```

Use `timer.cancel()` to cancel this subscription.

Usually the best way is to go with sockets or firebase approach in such Live Scoring apps so the data is automatically updated whenever there is a new update at remote.

Comment: if i want to call API here , how widgets will rebuilt and data is updated?

Comment: and How can i link my firebase to API response , i mean how to store sportsmonks api data to firebase and then access it ?

Comment: Edited my response, you will just call the API again and setState((){}) to rebuild the widget tree with new data attributes.

Comment: You should also look into this live score widget offered by spormonks: 
https://www.sportmonks.com/football-api/livescore-widget/

Comment: where i write setstate((){}) i just want to rebuild LiveScore card area

Comment: After data from API has been successfully received. In the end of the function maybe